# Stacked barplots

Tags: r, bar-chart

I imported my table, which included the information. It looks like this:
Categories Number Gender
1 278 male
1 13  female
2 890 male
2 60 female
3 80 male
3 1029 female

I tried to do a stacked barplot, which should show me on the xaxis the categories (1,2,3), on the yaxis the numbers, but the barplots should also show me the females and males in the different categories.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: please attach data to this.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to copy-paste result of `dput(your.data.frame)`.

Comment: Than you for your answers!

The name of my imported table is R

I tried the barplot like this
R <- table(R$Categories, R$Number)
barplot(R, xlab="Categories", col=c("darkblue","red"),
  legend = rownames(R), beside=TRUE)

but this seems not the right way

Answer (score 1):

Based on the data you provided I think you are looking for something like this, to me "stacked" means that the male and female number are on top of each other to also show the total. The `beside` argument buts the bars next to each other for male and female.

```
x <- "1 278 male 
      1 13 female 
      2 890 male 
      2 60 female 
      3 80 male 
      3 1029 female"

R <- read.table(textConnection(x))
colnames(R) <- c("Categories", "Number", "Gender")
dat <- reshape(R,direction = "wide", idvar = c("Gender"), timevar = c("Categories")) ##barplot requires a vector of heights or a matrix
colnames(dat) <- gsub("Number", "Category", colnames(dat))
barplot(as.matrix(dat[,2:4]), col=c(2,3))
legend("topleft", bty="n", col=c(2,3), legend=dat[, 1], pch=15)
```

### Stacked barplot

[image]

### Side-by-side

```
barplot(as.matrix(dat[,2:4]), col=c(2,3), beside = T)
legend("topleft", bty="n", col=c(2,3), legend=dat[, 1], pch=15)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your efforts and help!